# Make vba wait till explorer is ready

Tags: internet-explorer, refresh, wait, ready

I have a code that pulls down table data from urls.

There I need to make vba to perform a clik action (to unhide last table), **which gives back expected result only in debug mode.**

```
Set objCollection = html.getElementsByClassName("{a keyword is entered here}")

objCollection(0).Click
```

If I simply run the code, it seems like click action was not performed.

If I stop code run right after click command and then let the code again to run, then I get back the expected result.

I have tried many things:

- DoEvents
- separate sub ("Refresh_All_Data_Connections") advised in some other topic

where issue was similar

Can somebody help to find the missing code part?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a test with code below may help you to solve your issue.

```html
Sub demo()
 Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       
    IE.navigate "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\demo66.html"
    
    IE.Visible = True
    
  While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
  Wend
    Do Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Do Until IE.document.readyState = "complete"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
   Set Button = IE.document.getElementById("btn1")
    Button.Click
    
   
End Sub
```

You need to change the URL and button ID in above code. Further you can modify the code as per your requirements.

Also check that scripts are already allowed and IE not showing any prompt to allow it. It can suppress the click.

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work properly. It gives me back data in table that comes up after button click only if I run it in debug (at least button click and the next steps - I place there a breakpoint, press F8, then I can again let it run by pressing F5, so it gets stucked again at the point where I put my breakpoint.

Comment: An other issue just came up regarding my code. It can not be run on my colleagues' desktops. It has some problem with IE object. I have never experienced such an error. If I run same file on my computer it works fine (regardless to this button.click bug)...

Comment: @user3920146, On your colleagues machine. You need to add reference to 'Microsoft HTML Object library' and 'Microsoft Internet Controls'. Than after it can work. If issue persist than try to provide a sample code and detailed error message. We will try to make a test with it and try to provide suggestions to solve it.